# Can the initial hover delay for comment upvote/flag images be mitigated?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, usability

There is a noticeable delay the first time the upvote or flag images are "hovered over". Can this be resolved by pre-caching (using JavaScript) or combining several images into a single file (using CSS)?

This also appears to be the cause of the "loading..." [bug (?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31687/bug-during-upvote/34105#34105) that is occasionally (momentarily) seem when clicking to see the detailed the up/down votes.

Comment: This is one time and it takes 2 seconds. But it bugs me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All images are fully sprited now, so if you have one image, you have them all.

(there are some minor exceptions for a handful of SE 2.0 sites with special styling, but not for voting.)